# mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file mysqld.pid ended

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I was resetting MYSQL Password since I forgot it. I am using MYSQL 5.6.41 at Centos 7.

**I followed the following steps:**

1. Stop MYSQL using :

> service mysql stop

2. Start MYSQL in safe mode so that I can have full access without a password.

> sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

```
Above command ends with :

190822 20:37:38 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

[1]+  Done         mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

3. Check MYSQL status if it is running:

> service mysql status

```
This command always shows me iactive status:
 Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2019-08-22 20:14:22 UTC; 11min ago
```

Since MYSQL is getting dead after running mysqld_safe, 'mysql -u root' is denying to login.

I visited many links to solve this problem even I found the same problem posted by a couple of people but that did not work in my case.

Reference :

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-reset-a-mysql-root-password/

[Can't reset root password with --skip-grant-tables on ubuntu 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984956/cant-reset-root-password-with-skip-grant-tables-on-ubuntu-16)

[mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid prevent from server restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984848/mysqld-safe-mysqld-from-pid-file-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-pid-prevent-from-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved it using the following link and some modifications in the commands used in it.

[Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Modifications I did:

1. Stop MYSQL Server (Didn't work in my case)

> kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`

I used: > service mysqld stop

2. Start the MySQL server with the init_file system variable set to name the file (Did not work in my case):

> mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &

I used:

> mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init.txt &

Answer (score 1):

After search some hours without succcess, I finally find the way

When you execute

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Mysql use a file in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf

I comment the second line, and save like this

```
[mysqld_safe]
#syslog
```

Then I can execute the command without problems.
I have found in log /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
This error:
    [ERROR] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'log-syslog=1'.
    [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

And search on internet what is this variable.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230736/mysql-could-not-be-started-because-unknown-variable-log-syslog-1